# Using the reverse() command in Java?

Tags: java, reverse

Alright. I have looked through how to make palindromes, and it looks like using the reverse() method seems to be my best bet. However, in my code I have run into an error I do not understand.

```
import java.util.*;
public class retreiveInput 
{
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int fives = 0;
    public retreiveInput(){

        fives = input.nextInt();

    }
    public void check()
    {
        while(fives < 9999 || fives > 100000)
        {
            System.out.println("The number does not work! It is NOT 5 digits!");
            fives = input.nextInt();
        }
        String five = Integer.toString(fives);
        five.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(five).reverse().toString());
            if(five = five.reverse()){

        }
    }
}
```

At the reverse in the code, it is giving me the following error. "The method reverse() is undefined for the type String"

Any idea how to fix this? What the program is supposed to be doing is that at the reverse() point of the if statement, the program should be checking if the value of five is equal to the reverse of five.

Comment: The String class doesn't have a reverse() method, but StringBuilder does

Comment: So how would I go about using the StringBuilder to fix the if statement?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I figured the error was at `five.reverse()`. `five` is of type String

Comment: @TimCastelijns that's not the error. I suggest you to read the code first.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I do not see how the error `The method reverse() is undefined for the type String` is not caused by calling reverse() on a variable of type String

Comment: Remove five.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(five).reverse().toString()); that is extra code now that does nothing.

Comment: @TimCastelijns this code doesn't show that... Which means that this is not the relevant code to evaluate.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What about `String five = Integer.toString(fives);` and  then `five.reverse()` in the if condition?

Comment: @TimCastelijns right, my bad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Np I was starting to think I was going crazy

Comment: Can people please stop making edits that replace the code that causes the error with working code..

Comment: You might've been confused.  it was modified when I answered the question and the bad code was removed and replaced with working code, but he switched it back. @TimCastelijns

Comment: @RazsApps I know, I did the rollback myself

Comment: Okay.  Either way he responded to the answer below saying it works now.  :)

Comment: Palindromes are strings, not numbers. e.g. `00100` is a palindrome but `100` is not.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(five = five.reverse())
```

In the above code five is a string.  reverse is a method of StringBuilder().  You also have some errors present in your if statement. You want this

```
StringBuilder sbFive = new StringBuilder(five)
if (five.equals(sbFive.reverse().toString()))
```

Also note you can do this a bit faster.

The way to do it faster is to start on each end and meet in the middle during your comparison.  it takes half the executions :)

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you so much! The code finally works! I had spent hours in the library trying to fix it.

Comment: @user3348422 Sorry there was a typo with the Parenthesis.

Comment: @user3348422 please accept this answer when you can, and please don't edit the working code into your original answer. Doing that will confuse future visitors